# Can we overwrite mocked values returned in LWC Jest?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-jest, mock

I am mocking the values in a custom label using this from

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.unit_testing_using_jest_patterns

```
import myImport from '@salesforce/label/c.specialLabel';

jest.mock('@salesforce/label/c.specialLabel', () => {
return { default: "value set in test" };
}, { virtual: true });`
```

However, I need to change the mocked value again to  test another method , is it possible to change the mocked value returned multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

I thought it should theoretically by possible to mock a custom label differently on a per-test basis.  I explored some options involving `jest.doMock()`, as described in [this StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48790927).  But these patterns don't work in LWC.  I believe what's happening is the `@lwc/jest-transformer` does a one-time transformation per test file based on a `jest.mock` call at the top of the file, when you call it as described in the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.unit_testing_using_jest_patterns).

So unfortunately, I think the best you can do is create multiple test files, one per set of custom label values you want to test for.

For example, for this component...

**lwcApp.html**

```html
<template>
  <div>{label.myLabel}</div>
</template>
```

**lwcApp.js**

```js
import { LightningElement, track } from "lwc";
import myLabel from "@salesforce/label/c.My_Label";

export default class LwcApp extends LightningElement {
  label = { myLabel };
}
```

...you can test it like this:

**lwcApp_English.test.js**

```js
import { createElement } from "lwc";
import LwcApp from "c/lwcApp";
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
import myLabel from "@salesforce/label/c.My_Label";

jest.mock("@salesforce/label/c.My_Label", () => ({ default: "My Value" }), {
  virtual: true
});

describe("c-lwc-app", () => {
  it("displays label in English", () => {
    const element = createElement("c-lwc-app", { is: LwcApp });
    document.body.appendChild(element);
    const div = element.shadowRoot.querySelector("div");
    expect(div.textContent).toBe("My Value");
  });
});
```

**lwcApp_Spanish.test.js**

```js
import { createElement } from "lwc";
import LwcApp from "c/lwcApp";
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
import myLabel from "@salesforce/label/c.My_Label";

jest.mock("@salesforce/label/c.My_Label", () => ({ default: "Mi Valor" }), {
  virtual: true
});

describe("c-lwc-app", () => {
  it("displays label in Spanish", () => {
    const element = createElement("c-lwc-app", { is: LwcApp });
    document.body.appendChild(element);
    const div = element.shadowRoot.querySelector("div");
    expect(div.textContent).toBe("Mi Valor");
  });
});
```